# Suppose $a$ and $b$ are integers in the ratio $6:7$, what is the ratio of $(6a^{2} + 7b^{2} + 6a + 7b ) : (a^{2}+b^2)$?

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, contest-math, exponentiation, ratio

Initially I thought I can assume $a=6$ and $b=7$ and calculate the ratio of the given expression which turned out to be $\frac{644}{85}$ and this was not the correct answer provided for this question.

Then when I turned to the solution for this problem, this statement was written as part of the solution

> The degree of all the terms in the numerator is not equal and hence, the resultant ratio can't be computed.

I couldn't understand this statement. What does it mean? What's the theory behind this? I am just a little confused here and I am sorry if this question looks foolish but a little guidance will be helpful.

Comment: What happens if you use $a=12,b=14$?

Comment: To get the general point, suppose $a:b$ is $1:1$ (so $a=b$).  Can you compute $a^2:b$?

Comment: @lulu : If I use $a=12$ and $b=14$ then we'll get a different ratio. When I first saw this question, I was also skeptical about using the values of $a=6$ and $b=7$ directly, but then I thought this might be a tricky one where it just wants us to calculate the ratio of the given expression just by assuming the values of $a$ and $b$ and it turned out to be wrong.

Comment: If all the terms have the same degree, then the ratio is a constant.  But that's not the case with your example.  You can, of course, get the ratio as a function of $a$ (or of $b$) if you want, but that's usually not what is meant.

Comment: @lulu : so in order to get a constant ratio the powers in the numerator of all the terms should be equal to the denominator one, right? is that correct? here the total power in numerator is 6 and in denominator it is 4 and due to this difference squared power will always be left. Did i understand correctly?

Comment: The degrees should match.  $(a^3+3ab^2+b^3):a^2b $ is fine since every term has degree $3$.  Note that if $a=\lambda b$ we get $(\lambda^3b^3+3\lambda b^3+b^3):(\lambda^2 b^3)$ which is just $(\lambda^3+3\lambda +1):\lambda ^2$.

Comment: @lulu in other words, both numerator and denominator must be homogenous with the same degree. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  When in doubt, just replace $a$ with $\lambda b$ and see if the $b's$ cancel.

Answer (score 2):

I get a ratio of $\frac{7}{b}+\frac{559}{85}$ when calculating $a=\frac{6 b}{7}$ and $\frac{6 a^2+6 a+7 b^2+7 b}{a^2+b^2}$.

In turn, when setting $b=\frac{7 a}{6}$, I obtain a ratio of $\frac{6}{a}+\frac{559}{85}$.

The fact that squared variables $a^2$, $b^2$ are involved leads to a non-constant ratio (where at least one variable $a$ or $b$ is involved). If you use only linear terms in the denominator and numerator, we obtain a constant as ratio.

And when I use cubic terms, for example $\frac{6 a^3+6 a+7 b^3+7 b}{a^3+b^3}$, I get a ratio depending from a squared $a$ or $b$, namely in this case $\frac{1}{559} \left(\frac{4165}{b^2}+3697\right)$.

We can generalize this question by setting $a=i$ and $b=j$ and use an arbitary exponent $n$ instead of $2$ which leads to a ratio:

$\frac{j \left(b^n+b\right)+\frac{b i^2}{j}+i \left(\frac{b i}{j}\right)^n}{b^n+\left(\frac{b i}{j}\right)^n}=\frac{ia^n+jb^n+ia+jb}{a^n+b^n}$ where $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{i}{j}$

Comment: Hmmm...and we can not exactly say what is the value of $b$, hence this ratio can't be found and I get that. But I am just trying to understand the solution statement that has been provided and which I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes I think you have to treat $b$ as a variable dependent from $a$ based on the defined ratio. Solving that system of equations leads to the ratio depending from $b$.

Comment: @Ganit: Maybe it is because of squared terms? What haeppens if you use linear terms in the numerator and denominator?

Comment: When I use linear terms instead of squared terms, the ratio becomes  a constant.

Answer (score 1):

The integers $6$ and $7$ are in a ratio $6:7$, and plugging them in yields a ratio $644:85$. The integers $-6$ and $-7$ are also in a ratio $6:7$, and plugging them yields a ratio $474:85$. These two ratios are clearly not the same, so the ratio is *not* determined by the ratio of $a$ and $b$. It is a trick question.

Comment: Correct, I guess we have to treat both variables as depending from their ratio $\frac{6}{7}$ instead of just inserting concrete values into them.

Answer (score 0):

In $(6a^{2} + 7b^{2} + 6a + 7b ) : (a^{2}+b^2)$

we have the first two terms of same second degree homogenity so its ratio can be evaluated but the inhomogeneous second part of degree $1/L$ in linear units..

$$ \dfrac{ 6a + 7b}{a^{2}+b^2}$$

is different.. i.e. if we let $a:b= \dfrac{a}{b}=t\;$ it does not cancel, and so it cannot be evaluated in the same or in any other way.